# I made a video on on my page responsive, but now I can't center it

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I'm working on my third project for freecodecamp, making a product landing page. I embedded a video, and looked up online some code to make it responsive. I applied that, but now, no matter what I've tried, I can't get the video to center. I even tried to make a flexbox to use justify-content and center.

Here is the corresponding HTML and CSS code that I believe would have to do with centering my video (have not added anything to try to center in this example):

HTML

```
<section id="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<!-- my embed src here -->" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#video {
  padding-bottom: 55%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
#video iframe,
#video object,
#video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

I am very new to any coding language, and have been following freecodecamp. I was able to figure out how to embed the video in HTML myself but I got the CSS code from a source online. I tried adding

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

to the #video section of the CSS but it did not do anything. I've been frustrated throughout this whole project and it seems any logical thing I try doesn't do anything whatsoever. I hope this gets better.

Comment: justify-content: center; is for a horizontal center, if you want the iframe to be vertical center, you need to add align-items: center; to section as well.

Comment: I wanted it to be centered horizontally in the page, and what I did didn't do that. I'll worry about vertical placement later down the project road. Thank you. I believe that I got an answer below anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following code of CSS

```
#video iframe,
#video object,
#video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

with this one

```
#video iframe,
#video object,
#video embed {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

Comment: That certainly worked! Could you explain each attribute and why this works as it does?

Comment: Left 50% means the start of embed go to half width of container, transform: translateX(-50%) means go back itself 50% width;

Comment: `transform: translateX(-50%)` means that adjust an element to center according to the width of that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

To:

```
#video embed {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 60%;
   height: 60%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: what's "#video embed" for? I was using "#video". Sorry I am new to this. Also nothing like that worked or changed anything on the page.

Comment: also I am sorry that could have been a solution. I was used codepen and it was sort of glitching on updating my code correctly. I don't want to mess with it much more as a solution above worked well though.

Comment: It's ok. Here is a codepen for your reference https://codepen.io/ramseyfeng/pen/QoQLwK

Answer (score 0):

Your video wrapper is the one that needs the flexbox styles. So this should work:

```
#video {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex; // flexbox on the container
  align-items: center; // centers items against the main flex axis, vertically by default
  justify-content: center; // centers items on the main axis, horizontally by default
}
#video iframe {
  // nothing else needed on the iframe to achieve centering on the page. This will need more styles if you have more than one item in the flex container, ie more than one iframe in the #video container.
}
```

Comment: that didn't do anything at all but I was trying stuff like that myself in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry my codepen was glitching out a bit. That could have been a solution but I don't want to test it at the moment because a solution above worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to center your video wrapper element simply by giving it dynamic margins:

```
<styles>
    #video {
        padding-bottom: 55%;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 50px;

        /*display item as block element */
        display: block;

        /* align left and right margins dynamically throwing you right in the middle */
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto

        /* width and/or max-width must tell us how big video wrapper can really be */
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</styles>
```

If your video still isn't centered, then that means that it's parent element is not set width correctly.